# Is a backend API using node, mongo to slow for front end client to get results for live suggestions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, design-patterns, architecture, microservices

I want to write a series of small apps for myself as micro services. This is for practicality and self learning. I want these apps to be able to work independently, but build a separate frontend client that has a search bar that can find data across all of the services. I wanted to implement a live autocomplete with search results as the user is typing that will search across multiple databases.

My current approach was to split each app into two apps, backend API, and a frontend client. Have a common auth service that all of the apps utilize for authorization.

I think this approach would work fine except for speed and performance, which I am not sure about. It is a personal requirement of mine to be able to implement this search bar with autocomplete search results. This means it will have to make API requests to each service to get those results, it just feels like it might be too slow.

Also, in case anyone is wondering, I was planning on using node, express, and mongodb for backend. Probably go with node, express, vue or something for the front end.

Q. Does anyone have personal experience with the performance aspect of working with multiple APIs?

Q. If this approach is too slow, is there a better approach that still allows for a separation of the applications?

Comment: Why do you think it will be too slow in the first place ?

Comment: I just feel like there might be a lot of http requests to the backend apis across the apps, even if they are being made asynchronously. Having too many http requests feels like it could take at few seconds to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance will be depending on so many other factors before/with the number of rest calls. It is really hard to say anything beforehand.

But according to my previous experience if you need to provide such a search functionality for a autocomplete feature you may most likely need elastic search for that.

That means instead of sending a request to each and every service for each autocomplete request you should have an index to search in (partial or maybe all data you need to show in your frontend) and search that index first to find the corresponding items then ask for the remaining/full data to other services if necessary. Details are totally depends on your requirements.

Of course if you go that way you should also implement a data population/syncronization mechanism to elastic search.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I have heard of elastic search and forgot about it. I think this is the way to go.